# Is there a GetDefaultMediaUrlOptions function?

Tags: media-library

Does Sitecore (7.2+) have something like `Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetDefaultUrlOptions()` except for media URLs?

We have a library of extension methods off of `Item` to make things easier and it looks like when that was created over a year ago I ended up just using `new Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaUrlOptions()`.

My searches aren't turning up anything, so I'd like to know if I'm just missing something or if that's the solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is not.

`mediaProvider` definition in Sitecore is limited to

```
<mediaProvider type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" />
```

while `LinkProvider` definition contains lot of properties which are used as default options:

```
<add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" addAspxExtension="false" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="asNeeded" languageLocation="filePath" lowercaseUrls="false" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false" />
```

That's why Sitecore uses `MediaUrlOptions.Empty` when options are not specified:

```
public virtual string GetMediaUrl(MediaItem item)
{
  return this.GetMediaUrl(item, MediaUrlOptions.Empty);
}

public virtual string GetMediaUrl(MediaItem item, MediaUrlOptions options)
{
  ...
}
```