# Can I remove the language parameter from Media Library images via config changes?

Tags: media-library, multilingual

Using Sitecore 8.2.current we're seeing `la=en` added to a number of our media library (unversioned) image usages (`<img src="_.jpg?la=en" />`).

In Sitecore version 7.something (7.2?) the recommendation was to [override `GetMediaUrl`](https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/981) to work around Sitecore not having configuration options to cover this.

Is that still the best practice in Sitecore 8.x, or can we make a configuration change to workaround this?

In the master database we only have **en** in /sitecore/system/Languages.

Verifying with /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx, on `linkManager` we have `<add name="sitecore" languageLocation="filePath" languageEmbedding="never" />` (only relevant attributes shown).

In case it mattered, I also added `language="en"` to the relevant `<site>` declaration, to no avail.

Thanks!

### Update 1:

Thanks to some assistance in the comments, if we use `Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(imageField.MediaItem, mediaUrlOptions);` and set `mediaUrlOptions` to `new Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaUrlOptions()` or `Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaUrlOptions.Empty` `la=en` is not added

If we use `Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.ExpandDynamicLinks()` with a Rich Text field type image sources are expanded, but include the language parameter.

Comment: So, even with `languageEmbedding="never"`, the language still shows up in the image link?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: How are you using the `GetMediaUrl()` method? Are you passing the `MediaUrlOptions` as parameter?

Comment: Depending upon the usage, it appears he has it using `Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.ExpandDynamicLinks()` when pulling Rich Text content fields or passing [`new Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaUrlOptions()`](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/4652/288). Both are resulting in language being included.

Comment: If you provide the `MediaUrlOption()` as empty, it should not append the language. Example:` GetMediaUrl(item, MediaUrlOptions.Empty);`

Comment: Confirmed. But also confirmed via that that `new Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaUrlOptions()` is resulting in the same behavior (as far as language embedding). Strange. I'll update my question with these new details; thanks for helping narrow that down!

Comment: The `Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.ExpandDynamicLinks()` makes use of the LinkProvider values. So, check if the language embedding is never or try to set is asNeeded and see if it works

Comment: Yup, confirmed it's `never` via the admin showconfig functionality.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution for this? Our media links are fine when we're handling them ourselves, but have a la={language} parameter added to the query string when inserted in a rich text editor field. We run multi-site, multi-language with language embedding set to always, site resolution false.

Comment: We ended up creating a custom media provider to remove the language attributes. I'll throw it into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, we ended up creating a custom media provider.

### MediaProvider.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Resources.Media;
using Sc = Sitecore;

namespace Wsb.Sitecore.Media
{
    public class MediaProvider : Sc.Resources.Media.MediaProvider
    {
        public override string GetMediaUrl(MediaItem item)
        {
            return base.GetMediaUrl(item)
                .Replace("la=en", "")
                .Replace("?&", "?")
                .Replace("??", "?")
                .TrimEnd('?')
                ;
        }

        public override string GetMediaUrl(MediaItem item, MediaUrlOptions options)
        {
            return base.GetMediaUrl(item, options)
                .Replace("la=en", "")
                .Replace("?&", "?")
                .Replace("??", "?")
                .TrimEnd('?')
                ;
        }
    }
}
```

### Wsb.Sitecore.Media.config

Patch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <mediaLibrary>
            <mediaProvider type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaProvider, Sitecore.Kernel">
                <patch:attribute name="type">Wsb.Sitecore.Media.MediaProvider, Wsb.Sitecore.Media</patch:attribute>
            </mediaProvider>
        </mediaLibrary>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```